# Want to show custom message if user does not input valid value in build.xml

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have following code in build.xml.

```
<property-required>
        <input message="Please enter your answer:" addproperty="answer" validargs="y,n" defaultvalue="n"/>
</property-required>
```

Here, if user does not provide input y or n, then the same prompt (Please enter your answer:) is coming again and again.

Here, I want to show prompt with a custom message to user like "Please enter y or n.".
What other action required for this?
Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the Input property can provide that sort of functionality. You may need to look into creating an [InputHandler](https://ant.apache.org/manual/inputhandler.html).